# Is log4j compatible with Mac OS Leopard

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I am developing a Java application on a Mac OS Leopard. 
And I want to use Log4J and various logging.

Is Log4J compatible with Mac OS ?

So far I've only seen  Log4J used on Windows machines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  log4j is written in Java and can be used on any platform where Java can run.

You must, however, use the correct form of filenames for this particular system when configuring log4j.   `C:\TEMP\FOO.log` will work for Windows but not for OS X.  `/tmp/FOO.log` will work for OS X but not for Windows.